# How to make an array of struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, roguelike

I am making a roguelike game. I want to represent the map as an array of structs, for example having 256 structs in an array. The map is a 16*16 grid of tiles, and each tile has attributes, such as whether there is an item on top of it.

So say that I want an array of 256 of the struct `tiles`:

```
struct tiles {
        char type; /* e.g. dirt, door, wall, etc... */
        char item; /* item on top of it, if any */
        char enty; /* entity on top of it, e.g. player, orc if any */
}
```

Then, I need to access an array of that structs something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
        unsigned short int i;
        struct tiles[256];

        for (i = 1; i <= 256; i++) {
                struct tiles[i].type = stuff;
                struct tiles[i].item = morestuff;
                struct tiles[i].enty = evenmorestuff;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To declare an array of `struct tiles` just place this before the variable as you do with other types. For an array of 10 `int`

```
int arr[10];
```

Similarly, to declare an array of 256 `struct tiles`

```
struct tiles arr[256];
```

To access any member, say `type`, of elements of `arr` you need `.` operator as  `arr[i].type`

Answer (score 5):

You need to give your array a name.  If an `int` variable looks like:

```
int my_int
```

And an array of `int`s looks like:

```
int my_ints[256]
```

Then an array of `struct tiles` looks like:

```
struct tiles my_tiles[256]
```

Answer (score 5):

An array is a variable, just like an integer, so you need to give it a name to access it.

Note: the array has a lowest index of `0` and a highest index of `255`, so the for loop should be: `for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i)` instead.

```
int main(void)
{
        unsigned short int i;
        struct tiles t_array[256];

        for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
                t_array[i].type = stuff;
                t_array[i].item = morestuff;
                t_array[i].enty = evenmorestuff;
        }
}
```